# Iterate and change content of a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a script, which takes first and second parameter strings and the other parameters are files.The idea of the script is to replace the first parameter with the second in every line of every file .Here is my implementation ,however it does not change the content of the files ,but it prints correct information

```
first=$1
second=$2
shift 2
for i in $*; do
  if [ -f $i]; then
        sed -i -e 's/$first/$second/g' $i
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't change the files because you are simply just printing to stdout, not to the file. They way you did it, you would need a new variable to store the new content word by word and then echo it to the original file with redirection (`>`).

But you can do this simply with `sed`, like this:

`sed -i '' 's/original/new/g' file(s)`

Explanation:

`sed` is a stream editor

`-i ''` means it will edit the current file and won't create any backup

`s/original/new/g` means substitute `original` word or regexp with `new` word or regexp. The `g` means global = substitute all occurencies, not just the first for every line

`file(s)` are all the files in which to perform the substitution. Can be `*` for all files in the working directory.

Comment: I have changed the code with sed , and strangely it still doesn't make change :?

Comment: Oh I see it in your question now. The sed command I posted is all you need, don't put it in your script, run only this command and it will work. No need for those loops etc.

Answer (score 1):

You used a single quote to enclose the sed command. Thus, the special meaning of the dollar sign (parameter expansion) is ignored and it is treated as a simple character. 
Check out bash manual:

> Enclosing  characters  in  single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.
>   ... Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `,  \,  and, when history expansion is enabled, !.

You should replace them with double quotes:

```
sed -i -e "s/$first/$second/g" $i
```

Comment: Yeah that was the reason :)